# help accessing properties in Objective C iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

I have a navigation based project and I want to be able to access properties in the different classes of the project.

In my appDelegate I have the property:

```
UINavigationController *navig;
```

and then I set the `rootViewController`:

```
MainViewController *theMainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
self.navig = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theMainViewController];
```

In the `theMainViewController` object I have the property:

```
MyScrollView *scrollView;
```

So, to access this `scrollView` property from a different class, I tried the following:

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIViewController *mainViewController = [myAppDelegate.navig.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UIScrollView *scroll = mainViewController.scrollView;
```

However, it is not working. It doesn't seems to find the `scrollView` property. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you decline properties?

Also you should set appropriate type of `mainViewController` : it should be `MainViewController`:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = [myAppDelegate.navig.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```